# Heard bang while driving, car wont start

Tags: battery, alternator, fuse

I heard a bang right after shifting gears and I suddenly lost power to my radio and power steering. My engine was still running fine after the bang. But when I shut it off I couldnt start it again. Still no power to radio, cant raise windows, and still wont start. The gauge cluster still turns on and so do my headlights. Thought it might be the battery so I jumped it and still wouldnt start. Could it be an alternator problem or maybe a fuse?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with checking the fuses and the large fusible links.  If the bang was electrical, then a fusible link is most likely.

Before replacing a blown fuse, I would be checking that blown circuit for a short.  If there is a link between the fault and you changing gear, then maybe you have a wire that is rubbing against the body in the engine compartment and the movement of the engine from changing gear brought the conductors together.